# Can we pass multiple types of object(item) through single interface as per particular recyclerview item click

Tags: android, interface, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

```
interface ItemClickListener {
fun transferData(data : **I want to add any type item as per recyclerview click**)}
```

I have 2 different types of object to transfer like **Address**, **User**.

```
data class Address(
val city_name : String?,
val address_line_one : String?,
val address_line_two : String?,
val pin_code: String?)

data class User(
val name : String?,
val age: Int?,
val gender: String?)
```

I want to achieve that if i click on **User** list item then pass user clicked item through interface and if i click on **Address** list then pass address clicked item through interface.

Comment: Using Any and when you implementation interface you can check it is Adress or User

Comment: I think i need to add more object classes, so using when will get worse when object classes increased. I will try Any.

Comment: You can use sealed class, and both Address & User will extend to it, after that in the interface implementation, you can check the type and handle it appropriately

Comment: Agree with @mangkool good way you should extends from abstract class or sealed class

Comment: @mangkool I am not that much experienced can u share any example code

Comment: @akshaykondekar I post sample code in answer

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, you can use sealed class to achieve this, the code will be something like this:

```
// the sealed class
sealed class Data {
    data class Address(
            val city_name : String?,
            val address_line_one : String?,
            val address_line_two : String?,
            val pin_code: String?) : Data()

    data class User(
            val name : String?,
            val age: Int?,
            val gender: String?): Data()
}

// interface
interface ItemClickListener {
    fun transferData(data : Data)
}

// implementation, this could be in your activity/fragment
class Try: ItemClickListener {
    override fun transferData(data: Data) {
        when(data) {
            is Data.Address -> {
                // handle when data is address
            }

            is Data.User -> {
                // handle when data is User
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to share your knowledge with me.

Comment: @akshaykondekar no problem, don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer if this works for you

Comment: class AddressAdapter(val addresslist : ArrayList<Data.address>,
                        val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.AddressViewHolder>()
{
    inner class AddressViewHolder(var view : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        fun bind(address : Data.address, clickListener: ItemClickListener)
        {
            ... update ui....
            view.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener.transferData(address)
            }
        }
 }
}

Comment: when i set clickListener.transferData(address) it shows
required : Data
found : Data.Address

Comment: you don't need to specifically use address just Data. change your addresslist to arrayList of Data. I think you have different intention here from what you asked in your question